# Only creating object through factory class in Python - factory class related

Tags: python

C++ programmer here.

In Python, how do you make sure that a particular class (e.g. UsefulClass) can only be created through its related factory class (e.g. FactoryClass)? But, at the same time the public methods of UsefulClass are callable directly?

In C++ this can be easily achieved by making the relevant methods of UsefulClass public, and by making its default constructor (and any other constructors) private. The related FactoryClass (which can be a "friend" of the UsefulClass) can return instances of UsefulClass and thereby strictly controlling creation, while allowing the user to directly call the public methods of UsefulClass.

Thanks.

Comment: Typically, you just document that `UsefulClass` should not be instantiated directly, but via `FactoryClass` instead. An example in standard Python is using `open` to create a `file` object, rather than use the `file()` function directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the constructor throw an exception:

```
class UsefulClass(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        raise NotImplementedError("Create UsefulClass instances only with FactoryClass")


class FactoryClass(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Do interesting things here, like modifying args and kwargs
        in a fancy way :) then call the default constructor"""
        instance = object.__new__(UsefulClass, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance
```

This:

```
UsefulClass()
```

will throw the exception, while this:

```
FactoryClass()
```

will return a new instance of `UsefulClass`.
**Remember:** *Because of dynamic nature of Python, user of UsefulClass can still redefine constructor by monkey patching.*

Comment: This fails to call `UsefulClass.__init__`, which might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern as an object factory:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Inited Foo'

    def say(self):
        print 'Me is Foo!'


class Boo:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Inited Boo'

    def say(self):
        print 'Me is Boo!'


registrar = {
    'foo': lambda:  Foo(),
    'boo': lambda:  Boo(),
}
```

Then I can create any instance:

```
r = reg['foo']()
r.say()
b = reg['boo']()
b.say()
```

Output:

```
    >>> Inited Foo
    Me is Foo!
    Inited Boo
    Me is Boo!
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't.

Python is not C++ and using patterns that worked before are silly in Python. In particular, Python is not a "Bondage and Domination" language where phrases like "thereby strictly controlling creation" don't apply.

"If you didn't want to instantiate a `UsefulClass` then why did you?" — *me*.

If you can't trust yourself or your colleagues to read and follow the code's internal documentation, you're screwed regardless of the implementation language.

Comment: I agree...most of the time. The concept OP's is asking about is indeed unusual in Python. But...we don't see the big picture. Maybe creating instance of this class directly can harm data integrity somehow? Maybe OP doesn't know future users of the library he/she develops, so limited trust is legitimate? My answer is not perfect - it's rather an academic proof that something like that is possible to some extent, but we both know that some devs don't pay attention to docs but they still read tracebacks. Think also about unit tests. Writing tests doesn't mean that you don't trust your colleagues.

Comment: The difference between theory and practice in theory is less than the difference between theory and practice in practice. As the OP notes "C++ programmer here" and then asks how to abuse the language to provide a C++ish construct. While the code does fake that result, it does so in a most unreadable way. I'd reject it in code review. "A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools." — _Douglas Adams_